# AttributeError '' object has no attribute 'get' on returning an object in Get Request

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

This is the requesting url: GET /api/v1/companies/profile/?name=TestFirma 
I'm relativly new to django, and this is my first attempt at passing a parameter with a GET request in django.

I've tested using loggers that the name(TestFirma) actually passes to get_object.

I don't understand why Company should have an get method? What am I misunderstanding here?

```
def get_object(request, name):
    name = request.GET.get('name', '')
    if name is not None:
        company = Company.objects.get(name=name)
        return company
```

Stack:

```
[04/Jan/2016 13:40:49] "GET /static/templates/company/profile.html HTTP/1.1" 200 133
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/companies/profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\widewidewideass\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 223, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\widewidewideass\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 31, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
AttributeError: 'Company' object has no attribute 'get'
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/companies/profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\widewidewideass\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 223, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\widewidewideass\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 31, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
AttributeError: 'Company' object has no attribute 'get'
[04/Jan/2016 13:40:49] "GET /api/v1/companies/profile/?name=TestFirma HTTP/1.1" 500 75282
[04/Jan/2016 13:40:49] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 6524
```

Comment: is `Company ` a model class?

Comment: @VineethGuna Yes it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to return a JSON response of the object of `Company`. If that is what you want then you should serialize the object and then return it as a `HttpResponse` object.

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers

def get_object(request, name):
    name = request.GET.get('name', '')
    if name is not None:
        obj = Company.objects.get(name=name)
        company = serializers.serialize('json', [obj,])
        struct = json.loads(company)
        data = json.dumps(struct[0])
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='json')
```

Comment: Yes that's true, but I've used this before
http://pastebin.com/5CXBPzh9 .
Why does this work, but not in the case which I'm having troubles with?

Comment: @Patidati - That was just a simple method which could return any object. But in Django, A view function is a Python function that takes a Web request and returns a Web response. Doc [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/views/#writing-views).

Comment: @Patidati -  Basically each view function is responsible for returning an `HttpResponse` object (in almost all situations).

Comment: @Patidati - Made an edit to the answer. Do have a look.

Comment: Now getting TypeError: 'Company' object is not iterable. Any ideas?
Hmm okay I understand :)

Comment: Oh! Ofc :)! Now it makes a lot more sense :D Thank you so much :)
Just a quick question (if you have time) when would you use Response(data,status) instead?

Comment: Django uses its own built-in response class [`django.http.HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse). You should use that. You can read more about it from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#module-django.http).

Comment: You also have `django.http.JsonResponse` that makes it simpler.